# How can I replace content in a text file using apply function?

Tags: r, apply, mapply, write.table

I have a textfile where there are 2 arguments - starttime and endtime. I create 2 vectors with different times. I want to

1. Replace starttime/endtime with these times
2. Write out a different text file for every combination (3 in this case)

   ```
   runStart <- lubridate::ymd_hm('2016-01-01 00:00') #Start of the entire run
   st <- runStart + months(0:2) #Start times
   et <- runStart + months(1:3) - lubridate::dhours(1) #End times

   mult_one<-function(st,et){
   readLines("template.txt") %>%
   gsub(pattern = "starttime", replace = st) %>%
   gsub(pattern = "endtime", replace = et)
   }

   x <- mapply(mult_one,st,et)
   write.table(x[,1],'template_1.txt', row.names = F, col.names = F)
   ```

This is giving me the desired output.

But I want to write out the files inside the function. Preferably with `template_1.txt, template_2.txt, template_3.txt` as filenames automatically. How can I do this?

```
dput(readLines("template.txt"))
```

Here:

```
  c("", "\"! ***********************************************************************************************************************\"", 
"\"simulStart              starttime     ! (01) simulation start time -- must be in single quotes\"", 
"\"simulFinsh              endtime      ! (02) simulation end time -- must be in single quotes\"", 
"\"\"", "\"! ***********************************************************************************************************************\""
)
```

Comment: Make the example reproducible with `library(magrittr)` or whatever's needed.

Comment: @Frank Could you please check now.

Answer (score 0):

Based on information in your question, if I understood clearly, you would like to write 3 files inside function. You could do like this:

```
# Adding num_of_files as a third argument in your function. 
mult_one<-function(st,et,num_of_files){
   for (i in 1:num_of_files) {
      readLines("template.txt") %>%
      gsub(pattern = "starttime", replace = st) %>%
      gsub(pattern = "endtime", replace = et)
      write.table(.,paste("template_", num_of_files, ".txt",sep=""),row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE)
   }
}

## Then you just call the function in mapply with 3 arguments
x <- mapply(mult_one,st,et,num_of_files)
```

Note: Haven't tested the code since I have no test data. But, I hope this helps you.

Comment: No need for inner `for` loop. Pass in a vector equal length to *st* and *et*: `mapply(mult_one,st,et, seq_along(st))`, then the *num_of_files* iterates with other two.